# Use of a pipe prevents left process to export variables. Why?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, pipe

I have the following one-line bash file `foo.sh`:

```
export PATH=<new path>
```

In another script, I use:

```
echo $PATH # --> old path
. foo.sh | grep bar
echo $PATH # --> old path!!!!
```

Depending on the machine I execute this second script on, the PATH is or is not updated in the main script. On the machines where it does not work, whatever the command right of the pipe, it still does not work. On the contrary, if I drop the pipe, it always work whatever the machine.

My machines are supposed to have the exact same configuration (even though, considering this issue, it looks as if they don't). Bash version is 4.1.2.

Do you have any idea where/what to look to understand this behaviour?

Comment: Pipeline always creates a sub-shell. The command to the right of the pipe is executed in a separate shell

Comment: Yes, but the export is done in the command **left** of the pipe :)

Comment: So it's exactly what @Inian mentioned. Your `foo.sh` is executed in your current shell, the one you are interacting with. On the other side `grep  bar` is executed in a subshell which you can almost imagine as someone opened a new bash terminal and executed it. Whatever you `export` will be visible only in your current shell. You can test it with simple example `export bar='test' | echo "$bar"`.

Comment: I'm afraid I have not been clear enough. When I say the PATH is not updated, I mean **in the caller script**, not in the `grep` or any other process right of the pipe!

Comment: In bash *both* sides of a pipeline are executed in child processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `bash`, all parts of a pipeline are executed in separate subshells, which is why sourcing the script doesn't change the path.

*Some* shells are able to run the *last* command in the current shell environment (`ksh93`, for example), but `bash` does not (unless job control is disabled and the `lastpipe` shell option is enabled, and the pipeline is not executed in the background).

The `bash` manual states, in the "Pipelines" section,

> Each command in a pipeline is executed as a separate process (i.e., in
>          a subshell).